# Best way to determine root directory of project - even if in a web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, separation-of-concerns, system.io.directory

I have a constructor of a class which needs to look in the root directory for a settings file. This is working fine for most project types, I grab the directory like this:

`new FileInfo(typeOfThisClass.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.Location).DirectoryName`

However, this is not working if I execute the constructor from within a web project, like a Web API. Instead, I'll get a path to a temp directory instead of the current project's root directory, like

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\73891a9e\147b8ade\assembly\dl3\7d1ac62b\0064ea47_c6bad201`

In the past, I've used this to get the root directory of a web project: 
`HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath`

However, the Constructor in question does not have access to HttpRuntime because it's in its own encapsulated assembly, which should be ignorant of anything related to web projects. I don't want to pass the string in, because I require my constructor to be parameterless.

So how can I get the root directory in a consistent way that will work in any project, including web projects?

Comment: Hah, I may have just found it. I'm using .net core, so I think this is the one I want to use: `AppContext.BaseDirectory` 
thanks to http://www.anotherchris.net/csharp/6-ways-to-get-the-current-directory-in-csharp/

Comment: Server.MapPath("~")

Comment: @loneshark99 I think that would work if the logic lived in the web project assembly itself - but the logic lives in its own encapsulated assembly, ignorant of web things, and doesn't have access to Server or HttpRuntime

Comment: Have you tried this in the assembly,  Environment.CurrentDirectory.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @loneshark99 Environment.CurrentDirectory appears to be missing from .netstandard 

I think AppContext.BaseDirectory may be the replacement for .netcore. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @loneshark99 also `Environment.CurrentDirectory` does not always point to the directly of the assembly. If you start the program using it's full path name current directory will be the directory you called it from not the directory of the program.

Comment: `AppContext.BaseDirectory` didn't work either. I'm going to try this now https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1107

Comment: @KrisColeman  I was thinking instead of doing all this ... why not just have the setting file as a embedded resource in the dll. http://dotnetdevblog.blogspot.com/2009/02/accessing-embedded-resources-in.html?m=1

Comment: @loneshark99 thanks! I'm not sure if that will work since the settings come from another assembly. What i've ended up doing is creating an ISettings interface, and I'm using dependency injection with my host assembly to pass down a little concrete which knows about web things and can grab the right path for me. Thanks!